# Node.JS: Express Application Returning 502 Bad Gateway on CSS/JS due to lack of trailing slash

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, .htaccess

I'm running Apache to serve up Wordpress and want to run Express on the same server.

I've been able to redirect all requests to a particular domain through to port 3000 and server up my Node.JS app accordingly.

I'm running into trouble with js and css files though as they return a 502 error along the lines of DNS error, nothing found at localhost:3000stylesheets/style.css.

As you can see, I'm missing a trailing slash. Do I fix this by using .htaccess or in my app.js file?

Comment: Instead of redirecting to a port, use a [reverse proxy](https://alicoding.com/how-to-run-node-js-web-server-on-apache-in-centos-6-4/).

Comment: Exactly what I'm doing

Answer (score 1):

I was missing a trailing slash from the ProxyPass directive. Adding this solved the issue.